# Geolocation with Google Maps not working using PhoneGap

Tags: android, cordova, geolocation, position

I am using Phonegap (cordova-2.0.0) and I have put cordova-2.0.0.js in the assets/www directory with my other files, I have put cordova-2.0.0.jar in the referenced libraries. I have added the required code in the Android manifest and config.xml. And I have made an html file called 'storelocation.html', I want this file to get the user's current coordinates and pass those into Google maps which will make those coordinates at the centre of the maps. I am not sure what is wrong with the code in this file, could somebody please check to see if I am just being stupid?

```
<!DOCTYPE html "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>

<title>Device Properties Example</title>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.0.0.js"></script>
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;key=AIzaSyBlNOgoh-8Xg9_OYqUUxReMJZk4syLFayM&sensor=true"type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

// Wait for Cordova to load

document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

// Cordova is ready
//
function onDeviceReady() {
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError,         {enableHighAccuracy:true });
}

// onSuccess Geolocation
//
/* function onSuccess(position) {
    var element = document.getElementById('geolocation');
    element.innerHTML = 'Latitude: '           + position.coords.latitude              +   '<br />' +
                        'Longitude: '          + position.coords.longitude             + '<br />' +
                        'Altitude: '           + position.coords.altitude              + '<br />' +
                        'Accuracy: '           + position.coords.accuracy              + '<br />' +
                        'Altitude Accuracy: '  + position.coords.altitudeAccuracy      + '<br />' +
                        'Heading: '            + position.coords.heading               + '<br />' +
                        'Speed: '              + position.coords.speed                 + '<br />' +
                        'Timestamp: '          +                                   position.timestamp          + '<br />';
} 

// onError Callback receives a PositionError object
//
function onError(error) {
    alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
          'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
} */
            var element = document.getElementById('geolocation');


function initialize() {
if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));
map.setCenter(new GLatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude), 13);
map.setUIToDefault();

}
}



</script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()" onunload="GUnload()">
<div id="map_canvas" style="width: 500px; height: 300px"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Many thanks in advance, I really do appreciate it if one of you geniuses could help me out, I have been trying to see what's wrong for like 2 days now. Btw, the user's coordinates could not be found and the only way to find them (that I found) is to use geo fix using telnet but I want the phone to find the coordinates and not me.

Answer (score 0):

Hello i am basically trying the same thing as you. Geolocation on google maps with phonegap.

Could you clarify:
"Btw, the user's coördinates could not be found and the only way to find them (that I found) is to use geo fix using telnet but I want the phone to find the coördinates and not me."

A pc obviously doesn't have GPS so for it to work on your emulator, you need to emulate (fake) GPS coördinates.

Have you added google maps to the whitelist permissions?

link to my thread [Phone gap geolocation with google maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11688457/phone-gap-geolocation-with-google-maps)
Although i am using other code i am trying to accomplish the same.

Answer (score 0):

take care that you use the Google Api SDK and NOT the Android SDK.
Check in eclipse your build path => configure Build Path => click on Android and choose for example Google Api 2.3.3 / 10.